# Move all of the ‘music’-type files (.mp3) into the music subdirectory with the terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, files

I have tried `mv .mp3 /Music` but it can't find the file or directory `.mp3`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a pattern to match using wildcards.

Try this: `mv *.mp3 /Music`

See here for details on wildcards and path "globbing": http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Answer (score 2):

You have to be specific about the directory you want to move them into and which files you want to move.

You would do something like

```
mv *.mp3 ./Music/
```

Using the wildcard * will move all files with the ending .mp3 from the current folder to the folder called Music, which is located in the current directory. But you probably want something more like this

```
mv *.mp3 ~/Music/
```

The ~ denotes your home folder, where the Music folder is most likely located.

As you have it, your telling it to move a file called .mp3 to a folder called Music in the root directory /